# Convert a word into character array

Tags: c#, string

How do I convert a word into a character array?

Lets say i have the word "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" yes this is a word ! I would like to take this word and assign a numerical value to it.

```
 a = 1
 b = 2
 ... z = 26

 int alpha = 1;
 int Bravo = 2;
```

basic code

```
if (testvalue == "a")
{
    Debug.WriteLine("TRUE A was found in the string"); // true
    FinalNumber = Alpha + FinalNumber;
    Debug.WriteLine(FinalNumber);
}

if (testvalue == "b")
{
    Debug.WriteLine("TRUE B was found in the string"); // true
    FinalNumber = Bravo + FinalNumber;
    Debug.WriteLine(FinalNumber);
}
```

My question is how do i get the the word "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" into a char string so that I can loop the letters one by one ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to convert each character to your _own_ numbering/encoding? Is ASCII or UTF-8 not good enough?

Comment: I think you want to calculate which character is present in string & how many time it is repeated. right?

Answer (score 15):

what about

```
char[] myArray = myString.ToCharArray();
```

But you don't actually need to do this if you want to iterate the string. You can simply do

```
for( int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++ ){
  if( myString[i] ... ){
    //do what you want here
  }
}
```

This works since the `string` class implements it's own `indexer`.

Answer (score 4):

```
string word = "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
char[] characters = word.ToCharArray();
```

Voilá!

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple for loop.

```
string word = "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
int wordCount = word.Length;
for(int wordIndex=0;wordIndex<wordCount; wordIndex++)
{
    char c = word[wordIndex];
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) function to do this:

```
"wordsto".ToLower().Aggregate(0, (running, c) => running + c - 97);
```

(This particular example assumes you want to treat upper- and lower-case identically.)

The subtraction of 97 translates the ASCII value of the letters such that 'a' is zero.  (Obviously subtract 96 if you want 'a' to be 1.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ToCharArray() method of string class

```
string strWord = "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"; 
char[] characters = strWord.ToCharArray();
```