# C# - How to convert string to char?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, char

I am a beginner in C# and I would like to know how to convert strings to chars, specifically `string[]` to `char[]`. I tried `ToCharArray()`, but I then I got an error saying that it doesn't exist. `Convert.ToChar(<char here>)` gives me a error saying

> cannot convert from "char" to "System.Array"

Comment: You want an array of char arrays or a single array of all the chars?

Comment: you can not convert string[] array to char[] array by using this `stringValue.ToCharArray();`

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323405/convert-a-word-into-character-array

Comment: `Convert.ToChar()` won't complain about System.Array. Please be accurate when posting here, this is unclear and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Also, you may not even need this,you can use `someString[i]` to get at the chars.

Answer (score 66):

Use:

```
string str = "Hello";
char[] characters = str.ToCharArray();
```

If you have a single character string, You can also try

```
string str = "A";
char character = char.Parse(str);

//OR 
string str = "A";
char character = str.ToCharArray()[0];
```

Comment: Any time you want to simply pull a single character from a string, as either a string itself, or as a char, it's usually easier, faster and more intuitive to simply dereference the position of the string directly by its index.

i.e. (referring to the code above): `char character = str[0];`

Comment: It's still relevant in 2023. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For a **single** string [**String.ToCharArray**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netcore-3.1) should be used

```
string str = "One";
var charArray = str.ToCharArray();
```

For an **array** of strings

```
string[] arrayStrings = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
var charArrayList = arrayStrings.Select(str => str.ToCharArray()).ToList();
```

For a **single character** from a **single string**:

```
string str = "One";
var ch = str[0]; // means 'O'
```

Answer (score 4):

A string can be converted to an array of characters by calling the `ToCharArray` string's method.

```
var characters = stringValue.ToCharArray();
```

An object of type `string[]` is not a string, but an array of strings. You cannot convert an array of strings to an array of characters by just calling a method like `ToCharArray`. To be more correct there isn't any method in the .NET framework that does this thing. You could however declare an extension method to do this, but this is another discussion.

If your intention is to build an array of the characters that make up the strings you have in your array, you could do so by calling the `ToCharArray` method on each string of your array.

Comment: Strange, the tutorial I'm following had a guy converting an array of strings with char <name> = <stringValue>.ToCharArray(). For some reason visual studio won't even list "ToCharArray" as a possible method

Comment: Could you please share a link to this tutorial? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] myChar = theString.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Won't work, visual studio won't even show it as a possible method. It's like "toCharArray" doesn't exist, except it does

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] array = {"USA", "ITLY"};
char[] element1 = array[0].ToCharArray();
// Now for element no 2
char[] element2 = array[1].ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you want (requires `using System.Linq;`):

```
var result = yourArrayOfStrings.SelectMany(s => s).ToArray();
```

Another solution is:

```
var result = string.Concat(yourArrayOfStrings).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theString = "TEST";
char[] myChar = theString.ToCharArray();
```

I tested this in the C# interactive window of Visual Studio 2019 and got:

```
char[4] { 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theString = "1234";
char[] myChar = theString.ToCharArray();
```

I tested this in the C# interactive window of Visual Studio 9999 and got:

```
char[4] { '1', '2', '3', '4' }
```