# Error when i try to translate a string array to char array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I am new at c# and I want to create a calculator for school, but a get an error at line 45. Error Message: String must be exactly one character long. I think a have an error after splitting the String array and then save as a char array. But I don´t know why, maybe false character.

Code part:

```cs
string eingabe = txtergebnis.Text;   
string[] zahlen;    
string[] Operatoren;    
zahlen = eingabe.Split('+', '-', '*', '/');

Operatoren = eingabe.Split('0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9',',');

double[] dZahlen = zahlen.Select(double.Parse).ToArray();

char[] charOperatoren = Operatoren.Select(char.Parse).ToArray();

string stringOperatoren = new string(charOperatoren);
```

The Error Message is coming by char[].

I think I have a translation error from the string [] split

Comment: A string is already an array of char. No need to call `char.Parse`. If you just want a `char[]` use `ToCharArray` on the string. Off topic but I've been a c# developer since .NET 1 and I don't think I've *ever* see code that used `char.Parse` (for any reason)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char[] charOperatoren = eingabe.Where(x => x != ',' && !char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray();
```

About the error:
`char.Parse()` only accepts `strings` of length 1.

Some members of `Operatoren` contain more or less than one character (e.g. `empty string`).

Answer (score 0):

When you split on separate digits, then for instance a "12" would give 3 empty strings as result:

- before the start of the string
- between the '1' and the '2'
- at the end of the string

And an empty string cannot be a char. A solution:

```
Operatoren = eingabe.Split(new[] {'0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9',','}, 
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This would remove those empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in your case is using:

```
Operatoren.Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)).Select(char.Parse).ToArray();
```

Because you are splitting your operators by the numbers.

Think of you are processing an input of "1+2-3*4/5"
so your "split" results in:

```
['']['+']['-']['*']['/']
```

now if you will access the first member this call will end up in the exception you received because the first element is empty.

[Example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hyDnYv)

BUT be aware `char.Parse` is just accepting `string` with a length of 1 ([read documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.char.parse?view=net-5.0)) maybe you should consider using another parse option here. ([Other question which maybe help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946594/c-sharp-how-to-convert-string-to-char))