# Split word into letters C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to split a word into an array of all the letters leters in unity like `input: hello` `output: h e l l o`
Colud anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: `"hello".ToArray()`

Comment: Internally, a `string` is a collection of `char`, so any collection splitting method will get you what you want. `str.ToList()`, or `str..Select(x => x)` etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - How to convert string to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946594/c-sharp-how-to-convert-string-to-char)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.ToCharArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-6.0) to transform a [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) into an array of [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-6.0).

```
string input = "hello"; // your input string
string[] output = input.ToCharArray(); // ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

string glue = string.Join(" ", output); // glue the char array together with a space in-between
Console.WriteLine("The output is: " + glue); // shows the result (h e l l o)

glue = string.Concat(output); // glue together without a string/char in-between
Console.WriteLine("The output is: " + glue); // shows the result (hello)
```

I've also added the example to glue it together using [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) on line 3.