# How to divide a textblock into every single character to be able to analyze the characters one by one?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, code-behind, textblock

Good morning, I would like some help on WPF / C # (Visual Studio):
I have a TextBox where the user has to write a code that the program has to analyze. This code must be analyzed character for character because each character has a different meaning. How can I divide the text of the TextBox into every single character and then analyze it using the if? Thanks

Comment: A string is basicaly an array of char. So you can use index accessor (`mystring[2]`), `for` and `foreach` loop

Comment: When will the analysis be done: As the characters are entered? When a button is clicked? On some other event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a word into character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323405/convert-a-word-into-character-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps,

1. Assuming you want to read the text entered in a text-box on a button click in code behind (I am not following MVVM or some other pattern for you as of now).
2. Add below code in your xaml

   ```
           <TextBox x:Name="MessageTextBox" />
           <Button Content="Home" Click="Button_Click"/>
   ```
3. Add below code in xaml.cs

   ```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    string textBoxValue = MessageTextBox.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxValue))
    {
      // Display an error or warning message to ask user to enter some text.
       return;
    }
    else
    {
      foreach(char ch in textBoxValue)
      {
          // Now you have each character of the text entered in the textbox
          // You can write your logic now.
      }
    }
   }
   ```

Give a try using above statements and check it.